# CakePHP security component blackholing login (data[_Token][key] field not generated)

Tags: security, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

When I try to login, the request gets blackholed by teh `Security` component. How can I make it work right?

I have a simple login form

```
  <div class="container container-login">
    <h2><?php echo __('Login'); ?></h2>
    <div class="wrap-form-signin">
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login', 'class' => 'form-signin'));
    echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => '', 'placeholder' => __('Email')));
    echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => '', 'placeholder' => __('Password')));
    echo $this->Form->submit(__('Login'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller action goes like this:

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());             
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
            }
        }
}
```

And the `Security` component is included in `AppController`

```
public $components = array('Security', ... );
```

In the error.log I get:

```
2013-03-29 13:40:58 Error: [BadRequestException] The request has been black-holed
Request URL: /users/login
Stack Trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\cdx\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\SecurityComponent.php(234): SecurityComponent->blackHole(Object(UsersController), 'auth')
#1 [internal function]: SecurityComponent->startup(Object(UsersController))
#2 C:\wamp\www\cdx\lib\Cake\Utility\ObjectCollection.php(131): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 [internal function]: ObjectCollection->trigger(Object(CakeEvent))
#4 C:\wamp\www\cdx\lib\Cake\Event\CakeEventManager.php(247): call_user_func(Array, Object(CakeEvent))
#5 C:\wamp\www\cdx\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php(670): CakeEventManager->dispatch(Object(CakeEvent))
#6 C:\wamp\www\cdx\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(183): Controller->startupProcess()
#7 C:\wamp\www\cdx\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(161): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(UsersController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#8 C:\wamp\www\cdx\app\webroot\index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#9 {main}
```

How can I find what is making my request go to black hole?

When I tried to use a custom blackhole handler, the type of the error was `auth`. But that's all the information I can get

My version of CakePHP is 2.3.1

EDIT:
The login works well without the `Security` component. After adding it to the `AppController`, the login stops working.

**EDIT2: I don't have any `data[_Token][key]` fields in the form**

**EDIT3 THE SOLLUTION:
Someone from my team has overriden the HTMLHelper class and it missed "hiddenblock" in the _tags array, which resulted in missing _Token fields. For details, see mine and thaJeztah's answers along with the comments bellow them**

Comment: Can You set authorize in `$components` to `Form`?

Comment: this is what I have in AppController::beforeFilter(): $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
   'Form' => array(
    'scope' => array(
     'User.active' => 1
    )
   )
  );

Comment: tried settting authorize in components to Form, didn't help

Comment: In what action is the login form? Is it in the 'login' action? If not, you may have to configure [`allowedActions`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#SecurityComponent::$allowedActions) (although the documentation mentions this is for cross *Controller* requests). Another idea; have you tried to *not* generate the submit separately, but by automatically having it generated by using this; `echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));`? Not sure, but it may affect the calculated checksum

Comment: I've tried to use just the Form->end("Submit") but it behaved the same. Cross controller requests should not be the case, since the url is /users/login, which is the same action that handles the login.

Comment: Can you show the settings used for the SecurityComponent? Did you set any configuration options? Anything you're doing inside beforeFilter()? Is the form submitted using JavaScript?

Comment: There are no settings, it's actually just listed among other components. I just tried to add a blackholeCallback in order to find out the error type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In what order did you add your components? The security-component should be put *before* other components that handle form-data in their `startup()`:

*"If you are using Security component’s form protection features and other components that process form data in their startup() callbacks, be sure to place Security Component before those components in your $components array."*

[Security](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html)

Because the AuthComponent *does* handle form data inside the [`startup()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L281), I think this applies, so be sure that the SecurityComponent is *before* the AuthComponent in your $components array;

```
public $components = array(
    'Security',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        // auth component settings
    )
);
```

### Update

The 'final' answer as posted by the OP made clear that this question *could not have been answered*. as it turned out, somebody in the team made modifications to the HtmlHelper, causing it to *not* output 'hidden' blocks, and therefore *not* outputting the CSRF token.

**In normal situations, you should *never* make modifications to the CakePHP Framework files themselves. CakePHP offers ways to override its functionality (including Helpers) without modifying the 'core' CakePHP files.**

### Why modifying CakePHP files is *bad*

Consider, for example, a car. What if a mechanic didn't like the design and **decided to 'swap' the brake and accelerator pedals?**

Of course, the car is still able to drive **if you we're aware of this modification**. However, without this important information, any other driver would definitely *crash* (and wonder *what the heck just happened!?*)

If the default behavior of the framework doesn't fit your needs, extend those classes. Do *not* modify the framework files themselves (unless there **really** is no other option). If modifications to the framework are absolutely nescessary, be sure to discuss this with the team and write documentation on the changes that have been made.

Keep in mind that **it will no longer be possible to update the framework to a newer version, without applying the same modifications to the updated version as well**. Again, if the changes have not been documented, somebody might update CakePHP and destroy your modifications.

Also, *if* you override or modify CakePHP, make sure that the overrides are compatible with the default behavior of CakePHP and the unit tests of CakePHP still run correctly (or create new Unit Tests for the modifications)

### Using 'customised' Helpers in CakePHP

If you need to customise the CakePHP Helpers (or other components), there are various options to do so without modifying the CakePHP files;

**1. Extend the Helper**

```
class AwesomeHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper {
    /**
     * enhanced tableHeaders method, outputs tableHeaders in a 'thead' tag
     *
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function tableHeaders(array $names, array $trOptions = null, array $thOptions = null)
    {
        $output = parent::tableHeaders($names, $trOptions, $thOptions);
        return '<thead>' . $output . '</thead>';
    }
}
```

Then, use your Helper the regular way:

```
echo $this->AwesomeHtml->tableHeaders(array('Date', 'Title', 'Active'));
```

**2. 'Drop-in' replacement - use an alias (CakePHP > 2.3)**

Since CakePHP 2.3 its possible to use an alias for a Helper. This functionality can be used in situations where (for example) two Helpers with the same name exist in your Application (e.g. Plugin.HtmlHelper).

Also, this allows you override a CakePHP Helper with your own Helper. See the documentation here: [Using and Configuring Helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-and-configuring-helpers)

**Be aware that this will override the Helper *everywhere* in your application!**

```
public $helpers = array(
    'Html' => array(
        'className' => 'AwesomeHtml'
    )
);
```

Now, `$this->Html` will actually refer to the `AwesomeHtmlHelper` in your views:

```
echo $this->eHtml->tableHeaders(array('Date', 'Title', 'Active'));
```

Will output your 'enhanced' table headers

Comment: Thanks for your extended answer, but to make things clear, the main thing was not the missing hiddenblock tag, rather it was the absence of [_Token][key] input in the form, which I had to add in the secure() method

Comment: Just out of curiosity; if you try it without your modifications, is the token still missing? Looking at the source code, the token should be output by `Form::create()`, not `Form::secure()`. See [this line](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.1/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L439)

Comment: I won't be able to get to work until tomorrow, so I will check that then. But upon looking at the FormHelper source code, it seems like the same issue as with the other fields. Since the bounty ends in couple of hours, considering the amout of time you put in this and the probability, that you're right, I think you deserve it :)

Comment: Thanks for that, much apreciated, it wasn't about the bounty though, just curious if something else could affect the security behavior in case I run into something similar with a project.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: There was actually no error on the**

```
return $this->Html->useTag('hiddenblock', $out);
```

**line, it was rather a team member modification to the `HtmlHelper` I didn't know about that prevented `_Token` inputs to be printed in the page. The main issue remains, and it is the absence of `data[_Token][key]` input in the form, which I had to add**

---

I finally found out what was the problem. There were no `_Token` fields because of a possible erorr in `FormHelper` class. I had to edit the `secure` method that looked like this:

```
public function secure($fields = array()) {
    if (!isset($this->request['_Token']) || 
            empty($this->request['_Token'])) {
        return;
    }
    $locked = array();
    $unlockedFields = $this->_unlockedFields;

    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_int($key)) {
            $locked[$key] = $value;
            unset($fields[$key]);
        }
    }

    sort($unlockedFields, SORT_STRING);
    sort($fields, SORT_STRING);
    ksort($locked, SORT_STRING);
    $fields += $locked;

    $locked = implode(array_keys($locked), '|');
    $unlocked = implode($unlockedFields, '|');
    $fields = Security::hash(serialize($fields) . $unlocked . Configure::read('Security.salt'), 'sha1');

    $out = $this->hidden('_Token.fields', array(
        'value' => urlencode($fields . ':' . $locked),
        'id' => 'TokenFields' . mt_rand()
    ));
    $out .= $this->hidden('_Token.unlocked', array(
        'value' => urlencode($unlocked),
        'id' => 'TokenUnlocked' . mt_rand()
    ));
    return $this->Html->useTag('hiddenblock', $out);
}
```

This method returned an empty string. So instead of returning the result of `useTag` I simply returned `$out`.

One more thing I had to do is add the `data[_Token][key]` field. In the end, the method looks like this:

```
public function secure($fields = array()) {
        if (!isset($this->request['_Token']) || 
                empty($this->request['_Token'])) {
            return;
        }
        $locked = array();
        $unlockedFields = $this->_unlockedFields;

        foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_int($key)) {
                $locked[$key] = $value;
                unset($fields[$key]);
            }
        }

        sort($unlockedFields, SORT_STRING);
        sort($fields, SORT_STRING);
        ksort($locked, SORT_STRING);
        $fields += $locked;

        $locked = implode(array_keys($locked), '|');
        $unlocked = implode($unlockedFields, '|');
        $fields = Security::hash(serialize($fields) . $unlocked . Configure::read('Security.salt'), 'sha1');
        $key = $this->request['_Token']['key'];

        $out = $this->hidden('_Token.fields', array(
            'value' => urlencode($fields . ':' . $locked),
            'id' => 'TokenFields' . mt_rand()
        ));
        $out .= $this->hidden('_Token.key', array(
            'value' => $key,
            'id' => 'TokenKey' . mt_rand()
        ));
        $out .= $this->hidden('_Token.unlocked', array(
            'value' => urlencode($unlocked),
            'id' => 'TokenUnlocked' . mt_rand()
        ));
        return $out;
        //return $this->Html->useTag('hiddenblock', $out);
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you are either overriding the default HTML helper with a custom one, or changed the `'hiddenblock`` entry inside the `$_tags` property to an empty string? ([see: `HtmlHelper::_tags`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.1/lib/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php#L82)). If that tag is 'empty', then the token
will not be included in the form. The same `hiddenblock` tag is also used by the FormHelper to output the Token during `Form::create()` [see the source-code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.1/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L443).

Comment: If that is what is causing the problem, then you
don't have to modify the `FormHelper::secure()` as you did

Comment: You're right, it is a team project, so I didn't know my HtmlHelper got changed and it missed the hiddenblock. Nevertheless the [_Token][key] is not present in the form and I had to add it to the secure method.

Comment: I would really advise you to discuss this issue with your team. **You should _never_ make modifications to the CakePHP Framework files themselves.** CakePHP (at least since the 2.x versions) offers ways to override the Helpers without modifying the 'core' CakePHP files. *if* you override the helpers, make sure that the overrides are compatible with the default behavior of CakePHP and the unit tests of CakePHP still run correctly. I will write up an 'answer' with some examples and information.

Comment: I've naturally overriden the FormHelper instead of modifying it, i wrote it like this for the sake of simplicity, I never modify anything in the Cake files, but thanks for your point.

Comment: Fair point, please don't be offended by the update to my answer, see it as an advise to those people that don't understand the consequences of making modifications.

Comment: I am not offended at all :) I am glad someone put the effort to write something like your answer, which may be helpful to a lot of people and helped me solve my issue after all.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to test with the info you provided, but I would try to change the form create call into this:
`echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), 'class' => 'form-signin'));`

`auth` type of error indicates a form validation error, or a controller/action mismatch error. That could happen if the page where you display your form is NOT `/users/login`, as cross controller communication is blackholed when using Security component. Hope it helps

Edit: The validation error could also point to fact that you have not defined `username` for Auth component, checkout [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)

Comment: That's not the case, the login form has worked (and works) flawlessly without the Security component active, so the action is fine and validation does not even occur.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I cannot comment. Have you tried adding a callback to the Security component and see what exactly it is generating?

Look at: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#handling-blackhole-callbacks

What exactly do you plan on using the Security component for? What are you trying to prevent?

Have you tried using Session tokens instead of per form tokens? 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#csrf-protection

```
public $components = array(
    'Security' => array(
        'csrfUseOnce' => false
    )
);
```

Comment: The main thing I want to prevent is CSRF. The blackhole callback is returning auth type error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an user login form both from the login.ctp and using it from another view as an element and managed to fix this by closing the form with $this->Form->end() otherwise it will not add the hidden inputs form the Token.... Hope this help.