# Connecting `new \Cake\View\ViewBuilder()` to the main `\Cake\Http\ServerRequest`

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm rendering a view template into a variable via a new, standalone `ViewBuilder`.

```
$builder = new \Cake\View\ViewBuilder();
$builder->setLayout('my_layout');
$builder->setTemplate('my_template');
```

The above template contains a form.

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    'type' => 'POST',
    'url' => '/',
)).PHP_EOL;
$this->Form->unlockField('my_input');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

When submitted, it results in the below error.

> '_Token' was not found in request data.

As far as I understand, the tokens aren't being added because the `FormHelper` receives `false` [when it checks for `$this->_View->getRequest()->getParam('_Token')`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/38df4103a99d5fb6627e630711924d1a327104b8/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L630), and that is because this new `ViewBuilder` isn't connected to the actual request the application operates on.

Is there a way to connect my new `ViewBuilder` to the main `Cake\Http\ServerRequest` of the application?

Comment: It's normally passed via $builder->build(), 2nd arg. You sure you need to be making a new View builder, rather than just rendering a Cell or Element inside the normal View's template? How are you rendering this now?

Comment: @ahoffner, that was it, thank you! Had to pass `$this->getRequest()` as a second argument to [`viewBuilder::build()`](https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/class-Cake.View.ViewBuilder.html#build()). You're right that this needs refactoring, but will have to make it work in its current state anyway. Do you mind posting this as an answer? That way I can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it to [$builder->build](https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/class-Cake.View.ViewBuilder.html#build()), it's the the 2nd argument, you can normally get it from $this->getRequest().